# Excel Worksheet_Change Disables itself

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that creates a change log for a worksheet, and it's working well. If I modify and make a syntax error, VBA identifies the error as usual and I can correct and reset the module, but when I do this the Worksheet_Change subroutine disables itself. I have not found a way to re-enable the code, and I have to create a new workbook and copy/paste the code to move forward. Can someone tell me why this happens and how to enable the event program?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing both pieces of code.  Could you edit your question to include formatted code?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this happens all the time.  Typical event code looks like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False '<==== ALPHA
        '   do some stuff
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<=====OMEGA
End Sub
```

If you have bugs in "doing some stuff", you will never execute the line labelled `OMEGA` and Events never get re-enabled.

My suggestion is to include the following code in a standard module:

```
Sub Re_Enable()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

so you:

1. try your code
2. fix bugs
3. run `Re_Enable`
4. try your code again

Comment: Thanks Gary's Student. That fixed my problem.